# Search array path with related values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, parent-child

I'm working on a menu system and am working on some complex issues. The menu is generated from a array. This array is included in a pastebin because it's really big. I want to search in the array and get the hierarchical path of the value I'm searching while also getting the values next to the parents you run trough. As I said its quite complex.

In the pastebin is the array and the result I want to function to return:

[-->pastebin<--](http://pastebin.com/ZyX3PVTe)

I tried writing this function quite a few times but always get stuck in the middle.

Comment: I would say it's a rather ugly navigation implementation. It will get harder and harder to maintain as it gets bigger. You might want to rewrite this in some way.

Comment: @Silver Light: The reason for doing it this way is to avoid making multiple queries for every parent. Ultimately this is the fastest and cleanest way to build navigation without having to worry about your page making 40 or so queries. If you know something better you are free to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function:

```
function get_item_recursive($id, $menu_array = array())
{
    foreach($menu_array as $menu_item)
    {
         if(isset($menu_item['id']) && $menu_item['id'] == $id)
         {
             $menu_item['subitems'] = array();
             return $menu_item;
         }
         else
         {
             if(isset($menu_item['subitems']) && !empty($menu_item['subitems']))
             {
                 $found = get_item_recursive($id, $menu_item['subitems']);
                 if($found)
                 {
                     return $menu_item;
                 }
             }
         }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I have not tested it, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for the path to build something like a breadcrumb? You can use a recursive function for that:

```
function findPath($haystack, $id, $parents = array()) {
   foreach ($haystack as $k => $v) {
      if ($v['id'] == $id) {
         return array_merge($parents, array($v));
      } else if (!empty($v['subitems'])) {
         unset($v['subitems']);
         $return = findPath(
            $haystack[$k]['subitems'],
            $id,
            array_merge($parents, array($v))
         );
         if ($return) return $return;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Executing this function like this:

```
findPath($haystack, 11);
```

Would return:

```
Array (
   [in-balans] => Array
      (
         [id] => 2
         [slug] => in-balans
         [title] => In balans
      )
   [arbodienstverlening] => Array
      (
         [id] => 10
         [slug] => arbodienstverlening
         [title] => Arbodienstverlening
      )
   [arbo] => Array
      (
         [id] => 11
         [slug] => arbo
         [title] => Arbo
         [subitems] =>
      )
)
```